# How to return a user's group access permissions?

Tags: 7, group

I am trying to block a user from accessing certain content/blocks if they do not have permission to view content of a certain type within a group.

I have the user ID and the group ID, but how do I check the user's permissions for that group? I can't find any documentation.

To start, how would I print all the permissions for a given user and group?

Answer (score 0):

The [Group class](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/group/-/blob/7.x-1.0-beta6/classes/group.inc) has a userHasPermission() method you can use. So something like this:

```
if ($group->userHasPermission($user->uid, 'some permission')) {
  // do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$gid` contains the group ID and `$uid` contains the user ID, you can get the list of the permission names that user has on the group using the following code.

```
$group = entity_object_load($gid, 'group');
$permissions = $group->userPermissions($uid);
```

`$permissions` will contain an array with all the permission names.